# Creating a wizard in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently creating a "wizard" to create new projects inside my program. I have a solution that is almost done but it doesn't feel "right" and start to think about other solutions. Maybe should note that I also use MVVMLight.

My current solution:

- I have a window and the window contains custom user controls (they represent every page of the wizard).
- Both the window and the user controls share the same view model
- When you click back/next the view model handles which user control that should be visible

The problem with this one is that I don't like the shared view model. I have a shared view model because all pages configure different things on the same object and it's easier to follow. But at the same time thew view model contains a lot of things that each individuell user control doesn't need (for example only one page need methods to add/edit filters). It also makes it hard to re-user the user control later if I want them for something else than the wizard.

So should I instead create diffrent view models for the window and each user control and send messages between the view models with MVVMLights MessengerInstance? I feel that's cleaner but as a reader it's maybe harder to follow (something I feel in general when I sending messages around)?

With messenger it would be a workflow like this:

1. User enter all the information on a "page"
2. User click on next (that belongs to the window)
3. The windows view model have to send a message to the user control to check if all the data is valid
4. The user control check the data and have to send back if it's valid or not. If it's valid tell the next page to get visible, if not show error message.

So it would be a lot of messages back and forth that I don't need with the shared view model solution.

Or is there a better solution that I should do?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the shared view model. You could define separate interfaces for the view models of the individual user controls. Then, your concrete view model implements all of them and you keep the view decoupled from the view model.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the answers you receive here are primarily opinion based, but here goes anyway.

Currently, your view model has more than one responsibility, and therefore, more than one reason to change. It's certainly a good idea to split up your view models into smaller, more manageable classes. This may appear to reduce readability, however I would disagree. The idea of ensuring that classes only have **one responsibility** keeps things simple and promotes re-use.

That being said, your *main* view model will most likely hold references to **many** other *child* view models, but this isn't the end of the world, in fact, it's a good thing. The parent-child relationship between your view models is much like the parent-child relationship in your views. For example, a `Window` contains many `UserControls`, there's nothing wrong with mimicking this relationship with the view models.

Now, there are of course a few ways to communicate between view models. I personally prefer to use **events**, where a child view model raises an event that the parent view model subscribes to. Pretty simple, really. Although there is some degree of coupling in this scenario, you could of course abstract your classes away into **interfaces** and use **dependency injection** to inject them into the parent view model. Using events is down to personal preference, however MVVMLight has quite a nice `MessengerInstance` that decouples view models even further.

So. My suggestion:

- Work out the **responsibilities** of your view model.
- Split up the massive view model into smaller view models (based on the responsibilities).
- Create a parent-child relationships between view models. Your view will in fact point you in the right direction in terms of the relationships.